# Neural Network visualization for detection task

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, visualization, object-detection

I'm currently working with SqueezeDet for detection purposes. I trained the network on synthetic data and it performs reasonably well. [detection results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwFi0.png)

For my project I would like to be able to visualize which parts of the input were more relevant for the detection process. So in case of the detection of a pedestrian, I'd assume that its pixel would be more important than for example the surroundings. I tried a couple of different methods, but none of them is fully satisfactory. 
I did my own research and couldnt't really any papers that talk about visualization for object detection. So I implemented [VisualBackProp](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05418.pdf), the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auhl6.png) however don't look all to promising. If instead I compute the [relevance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emi6L.png) things look slightly better, but still not as expected. 
I started thinking that perhaps the issues might be related to the complexity of my outputs, with respect to a network that might only be dealing with classification, or as in the VisualBackProp paper just the prediction of steering angle.

I was wondering if anyone has idea of what visualization technique might best suit the detection task.

Answer (score 0):

You could try just augmenting different areas of the image and see how it affects the detection confidence. For example, you could put the area containing the pedestrian on just a black background instead of the natural background to see how much the surroundings actually affect things. You could also add moderate to severe noise to select areas of the image and observe which areas correspond to the biggest change in detection confidence.

More directly, mathematically you seem to be interested in the gradient of detection confidence WRT pixel data. Depending on what deep learning platform you are using, if you run a single training iteration you may be able to obtain the gradients in the data layer (dL/dx) which will directly show these. This will only represent the effect of small changes to the pixel data - if you are aiming for more macroscopic insights than that, I think my first suggestion is probably your only option.